# Can I run the maximum number of threads simultaneously on single process in a quad core system

Tags: multithreading, process, parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-cores

So I have a quad core single cpu with 2 hyperthreads per core, thus I can run a maximum of 8 threads simultaneously. So my question is that can I run all 8 threads simultaneously in a single process?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can have as many threads in a single process as OS-dependent resource limits permits. However, not more than 8 threads in your case will be running at the same time.

Comment: So 8 threads can run in parallel in a single process?

Comment: yes, 8 threads could run in parallel